# How to access the name of a control from another class?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have in my project my MainPage in which I have a control, and a ViewModel in which I control what that control does with Bindings. What I need to do is be able to access the x: Name of that control from the ViewModel but I don't know how to do it because I can't assign it a Binding. Any solution?

My code:

MainPage.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Using.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:fav="clr-namespace:Aname.Xamarin.UIControls.Controls;assembly=Aname.Xamarin.UIControls"
    x:Name="page">

    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50">
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="MyFloatingButton"
                        TextColor="White"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </Frame>

                <Button Text="test" />
                <Button Text="test" />
                <Button Text="test" />
                <Button Text="test" />
                <Button Text="test" />
                <Button Text="test" />


            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>



        <!--  This is the FloatingButton  -->
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,AutoSize,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">

            <fav:FloatingButton
                CollectionViewVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                ItemSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                PrimaryButtonColor="{Binding FirstButtonColor}"
                PrimaryImageSource="{Binding FirstImage}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();

    }
  
  
}
```

Button.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Aname.Xamarin.UIControls.Controls.FloatingButton"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="FloatingButtonView">
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="listView"
            Margin="0,0,21,0"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=CollectionViewVisible}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=ItemSource}"
            Rotation="180"
            WidthRequest="55">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid
                        Padding="5"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />


                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />


                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--  This ImageButton contais the data of the list  -->

                        <ImageButton
                            x:Name="listita"
                            Padding="10"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorButton}"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=BindingContext.MethodCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                            CornerRadius="70"
                            HeightRequest="45"
                            Rotation="180"
                            Source="{Binding Image}"
                            WidthRequest="45" />



                    </Grid>


                </DataTemplate>



            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>

        <ImageButton
            Margin="15"
            Padding="15"
            BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=PrimaryButtonColor}"
            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=BindingContext.OpenFloating}"
            CornerRadius="70"
            HeightRequest="70"
            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=PrimaryImageSource}"
            WidthRequest="70" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Since you had used MVVM , it would be better to avoid access Element and View in ViewModel (And we can only set x:name in xaml). What effect do you want to achieve ? I think we could found a better solution without access the control .

Comment: My control is a FloatingButton. What I would like to do is be able to access this control from ViewModel so that when I click it, I can make an animation on the button.

Comment: Could you provide the code of FloatingButton (xaml and code behind) ?

Comment: Check my update

Comment: https://xamgirl.com/plug-and-play-animations-in-xamarin-forms/
check this for animation in MVVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the Floafing Button as parameter to the command .

#### in Floafing Button .xaml

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            //...
             x:Name="FloatingButtonView">
```

```
<ImageButton
       x:Name="listita"
       Padding="10"
      
       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=LaunchWeb}"
       CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatingButtonView}, Path=Website}"
       //...  
/>
```

#### in Floafing Button .xaml.cs

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty LaunchWebProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LaunchWeb), typeof(ICommand), typeof(FloatingButton));

    public ICommand LaunchWeb
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(LaunchWebProperty);
        set => SetValue(LaunchWebProperty, value);
    }



    public static BindableProperty WebsiteProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Website), typeof(object), typeof(FloatingButton));

    public object Website
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(WebsiteProperty);
        set => SetValue(WebsiteProperty, value);
    }
```

#### in ContentPage

```
<fav:FloatingButton
                x:Name="FloatButton"
                CollectionViewVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                ItemSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                LaunchWeb="{Binding xxxCommand}"
                Website="{Binding Source={x:Reference FloatButton},Path=.}"
                PrimaryButtonColor="{Binding FirstButtonColor}"
                PrimaryImageSource="{Binding FirstImage}" />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
 public ICommand xxxCommand { get; set; }
```

```
xxxCommand = new Command((obj)=> {

   var FloatButton = obj as FloatingButton  ;
   //... do something you want  
            
 });
```

Comment: I can't use this code for my FloatingButton.xaml. I already have Commands in ImageButton. I edited my post with the current FloatingButton code.

Comment: Which ImageButton did you want to click and play animation ?

Comment: My idea was that when I clicked the main button it would make a small animation and then that the other small buttons, when appearing and disappearing, would appear with fade. With being able to animate at least one it serves me

Comment: If so you can check my code , set the command and command parameter of ImageButton .

Comment: xxxCommand in my code is just for demo , you could define it as any command like openFloatingButton .